# Breakpoint that activates only when variable hits a specific value

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am debugging a program that has a lot of for loops, each one with hundreds of values to loop through.

Within all this, I'd like to determine that behaviour of a variable when it reaches a certain value.

However, to do so, I would have to manually cycle step through all the loops and make sure not to space out. It would take me hours.

Is there a way to set a breakpoint that only activates when the variable is a certain value?

Comment: Those are often called "watchpoints". In most debuggers you can set a "watch" on a variable, when either it changes value or when a specific expression is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is called conditional breakpoints.

Visual Studio 2010 does support conditional breakpoints, you can just create your breakpoint, right click it and then click on Condition.

Answer (score 3):

Just insert in the cycle something like

```
If(Variable==value)
{
 int unuseful=0;
}
```

and set the breakpoint on the operation inside the if

Comment: While conditional breakpoints work fine, I prefer this more basic method as long as you have easy means to do so. It is a bit easier to manage than dealing with conditional breakpoints.

Comment: It's important to not build with any kind of optimizations if using this, as otherwise the compiler might optimize it away.

Comment: Can you add or remove these mid-debug?

Comment: To prevent optimization you can always just do `MulDiv(1,1,1);`. It's probably not a great idea to add/remove/change these types of conditions during a debugging session.

Comment: You could have value as a variable, so, while debugging, you change the value of "value" and "move" your breakpoint to whatever value you want

Answer (score 3):

Create a conditional breakpoint. These can be set up to break when

- the value at an address changes, which is useful if you are looking for when a variable is set
- the value of a variable equals a particular value, which is the case you are looking for

There are other nice uses of conditional breakpoints so you don't have to put a hard breakpoint as you noted.